# Weather data property returning "Not Applicable"

Tags: curated-data

When I try to use most weather data fields from Mathematica I get a "Not Applicable" error:

```
WeatherData["Chicago", "Properties"]
(* Out:  
 {AlternateStandardNames, CloudCoverFraction, CloudHeight, CloudTypes, Conditions, 
  Coordinates, DewPoint, Elevation, Humidity, Latitude, Longitude, MaxTemperature, 
  MaxWindSpeed, MeanDewPoint, MeanHumidity, MeanPressure, MeanStationPressure, 
  MeanTemperature, MeanVisibility, MeanWindChill, MeanWindSpeed, Memberships, MinTemperature,
  NCDCID, PrecipitationAmount, PrecipitationRate, PrecipitationTypes, Pressure, 
  PressureTendency, SnowAccumulation, SnowAccumulationRate, SnowDepth, StationName, 
  StationPressure, Temperature, TotalPrecipitation, Visibility, WBANID, WindChill, 
  WindDirection, WindGusts, WindSpeed, WMOID}
*)


WeatherData["Chicago", "MaxTemperature"]
(* Out: Missing[NotApplicable] *)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong; those properties are simply not there in the database. For instance, if you try `WeatherData["Chicago", #] & /@ WeatherData["Chicago", "Properties"]` you will see that some of the properties do have values, but unfortunately most simply don't for that locale...